# OwnsMany and table splitting in EF6 code first : How?

Tags: ef-core-6.0

In the most recent versions of EF (code first, Fluent Api), table splitting has been made easy for **owned** entities that are configured with `OwnsOne` (i.e. one-to-one relationship) : We simply use `ToTable`.

Example from EF documentation :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#storing-owned-types-in-separate-tables

```
ownerBuilder.Entity<OwnerEntity>()
     .OwnsOne(
        owner => owner.OwnedEntity, 
        ownedBuilder => { ownedBuilder.ToTable("OwnedEntities"); }
       );
```

However, if I decide to make it a **one-to-many** relationship, I'll need to use `OwnsMany`. for that one, there is no `ToTable` method available.

So, how do I configure both things?

- A one-to-many **owned** relationship
- the many owned entities being stored **in a table of my choice**.

In all my googling I haven't found an example of that dual scenario.

Comment: The type of `ownedBuilder` for `OwnsMany` is the same as for `OwnsOne`, hence has the same methods, including `ToTable`.

Comment: Incorrect. Did you try?

Comment: Of course. Both are of type `OwnedNavigationBuilder<TEntity,TRelatedEntity>`. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.entitytypebuilder-1.ownsmany?view=efcore-6.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-metadata-builders-entitytypebuilder-1-ownsmany-1(system-linq-expressions-expression((system-func((-0-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))))))-system-action((microsoft-entityframeworkcore-metadata-builders-ownednavigationbuilder((-0-0))))))...

Comment: ... and compare it to  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.entitytypebuilder-1.ownsone?view=efcore-6.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-metadata-builders-entitytypebuilder-1-ownsone-1(system-linq-expressions-expression((system-func((-0-0))))-system-action((microsoft-entityframeworkcore-metadata-builders-ownednavigationbuilder((-0-0)))))). The builder argument [type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.ownednavigationbuilder-2?view=efcore-6.0).

Comment: I've tried again and indeed now the ToTable has magically appeared in the intellisense. I am completely confused. Obviously a human mistake on my part, but... I've spent way too long on this. *cries*. Write what you wrote in a "real" answer and I'll approve it.

Comment: No problem, it happens :-)